# C String manipulation

Tags: c

I have a simple question. I have a string "ls -l -a" how would I extract the letters before the first space? "ls" or another example "date -u" extracting "date"

Thank you

Comment: `char input[] = "ls -l -a"; char* result = strtok(input, " ");`?

Comment: Use `strtok`, but note that the string needs to be writable.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Is this one of those "Write a shell" homework problems?

Comment: Maybe.. @Joshua

Comment: If you're sure there is a space, for a max 9 chars result, `char *str = "ls -la" ; char res[10] ; char *s = strchr(str, ' '); int l = s - str; strncpy(res, str, l); res[l] = 0;` this one does not need the str initial string to be writable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to assume it is a write-your-own-shell question.

So the direct and obvious method is to call `strtok()` to split on spaces. However, splitting on spaces is completely wrong here and leads down a garden path to disaster.

We usually start out with things like `ls -a -l` and `date -u` as input. These aren't so bad and it looks like a split on space works.

But then we add things like `ls -1 | wc -l`. Seems not so bad, only it might be `ls -1|wc -l`. Ok fine. Split on `|` then space, right? Wrong! Try this one: "ls "my projects"`. It doesn't work so good now.

We need to actually parse the input string, and to do that we need the complete grammar that needs to be implemented. Asking half the question doesn't work. The "split" part you're asking about becomes a function that returns the next token. I usually write it something like this:

```
struct lexerstate {
    const char *location;
    int state;
};

struct token {
    const char *token; /* if NULL, next token was bad */
    size_t size;
    int owns; /* You'll eventually discover why */
};

#define STATE_TOP 0
#define STATE_END 1
#define STATE_SYMBOL 2
#define STATE_QUOTE 3

void freetoken(struct token token) { if (token.owns) free(token.token); }

struct lexerstate InitLexer(const char *string) { struct lexerstate init = {string, STATE_TOP}; return init; }

struct token NextToken(struct lexerstate *state)
{
    struct token result;
    while (*state->location == ' ' || *state->location == '\t')
    {
        ++state->location;
    }
    result.token = state->location;
    result.owns = 0;
    if (!state->location) { result.size = 0; return result; }
    switch (*state->location) {
        case '|': result->size = 1; break;
        case '\"':
            state->location += 1;
            result->token = state->location;
            while (*state->location != '\"') {
                /* TODO FIXME implement \ escapes */
                if (!*state->location) {
                    result->token = NULL;
                    return result;
                }
                ++state->location;
            }
            result->size = state->location - result->token;
            ++state->location;
        default:
            while (*state->location 
                && *state->location != '|') {
                /* TODO FIXME abc\"def\"ghi */
                /* TODO FIXME implement \ escapes */
                ++state->location;
            }
            ++state->location;
    }
    return result;
}
```